# How to return matching value in textbox?

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a combo box that is populated by a csv. In my csv, I have 3 columns, the first column is id #s.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try **ValueMember**.

This is an example :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Student> listStudents = new List<Student>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listStudents.Add(new Student(101, "name1", "male"));
        listStudents.Add(new Student(102, "name2", "female"));
        listStudents.Add(new Student(103, "name3", "female"));
        listStudents.Add(new Student(104, "name4", "male"));

        var maleStudentList = listStudents.Where(student => student.gender == "male").ToList();

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DataSource = maleStudentList;
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = ((Student)comboBox1.SelectedItem).id.ToString();
    }
}
class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }

    public Student(int id, String name, String gender)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Source : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsmobile/en-US/1a978579-1938-44cd-aab3-d1964548a814/why-dont-comboboxs-item-have-a-tag-property?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a class to represent a row in the CSV file and have your properties represent the columns. The reason for this is because you could then convert the CSV file to a list of your class and then bind the ComboBox to the list.

When you bind your ComboBox you will set the DisplayMember to the Description and the ValueMember to the Id.

I'm not sure how you're reading the CSV file nor do I know the name of your second column, so I'm making some assumptions in my example, but it should plenty to go off of. Please keep in mind, that there are likely better ways of parsing CSV files, this is just an quick example to demonstrate how the binding would work.

This is how you'd define your class:

```vb
Public Class CsvRow
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Column2 As String
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

This is how you'd read the CSV and bind the objects.

```vb
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("my-file.csv")
Dim rows As New List(Of CvsRow)()

For Each line In lines
    Dim cells() As String = line.Split(","c)
    Dim row As New CvsRow()
    If (cells.Length = 3 AndAlso Integer.TryParse(cells(0).Trim(), row.Id) Then
        row.Column2 = cells(1)
        row.Description = cells(2)
        rows.Add(row)
    End If
Next

Dim binder As New BindingSource()
binder.DataSource = rows

ComboBoxDescription.DataSource = binder.DataSource
ComboBoxDescription.DisplayMember = "Description"
ComboBoxDescription.ValueMember = "Id"
```

Now in the ComboBox's SelectedValueChanged you can get the SelectedItem and convert it back to a CsvRow to get the properties:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBoxDescription_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxDescription.SelectedValueChanged
    If (ComboBoxDescription.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim row As CvsRow = DirectCast(ComboBoxDescription.SelectedItem, CvsRow)
        'row.Id and row.Description are now available
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: One point to note is that you should pretty much always set the `DataSource` last, after setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a class called `Product` with 3 properties. I guessed that the middle column would be the name of the product. When you add an object to a combo box, the combo will call `.ToString` on the object to get what to display. I provided an override of the `.ToString` method to tell the combo to display the name property of the `Product` object. Finally, I replaced the default constructor with a parameterized one to make creating the `Product` with all its properties easier.

In the `FillCombo` method (probably called from the Form.Load) I read your data file. You can change that to however you are reading the file. The important part is where you call the `New` method of the product adding each of the properties from your file. The entire `Property` object will all its properties are added to the combo box.

The `SelectedIndexChanged` event shows you how to retrieve the properties and display them wherever you want. To the combo box, it is an `Object`. You must cast it back to a `Product` to be able to access its properties.

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
    Public Sub New(iID As Integer, sName As String, sDesc As String)
        ID = iID
        Name = sName
        Description = sDesc
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub FillCombo()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("data.csv")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim props = line.Split(","c)
        Dim p As New Product(CInt(props(0)), props(1), props(2))
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(p)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim p = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Product)
    TextBox1.Text = p.ID.ToString
    TextBox2.Text = p.Description
End Sub
```